TargetPath is different from Linker Output File
ALL,
In my solution I have one binary project and 15 DLL projects.
In each DLL project I set the linker OutputFile property to place the DLL in the directory where the binary is created in order to not do it manually.
This change however introduces the warning mentioned above.
Now it looks like the vast majority of the solution about the warning is to change "Properties -> Linker -> General -> OutputFile".
However, is it OK if I change TargetPath? What difference will it be?
Is it acceptable solution?
TIA!!!
Working with MSVC 2017
